# Counter in Tia Portal software

Tags: range, counter, structured-text

I have an issue with a counter in the Tia portal software.

When I hover over the CV, it says you can insert Int, DInt, SInt UInt, USint, UDint.

I want to insert a Dint value because the number can be bigger than 32767.

But when I do this, it still stops at 32767.

How is this possible?

I got the following code

[image: my code]

`V2.DI_BatchProduction` is a `DInt`. (int32)

So why does it stops at 32767? (the max value of a int16)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems you can tell the counter what kind of counter it is. when you click on the name of the counter you get a dropdown and you can select what kind of counter it is (see image below)

[image: example changing counter]

pretty strange this isn't changed automatically on the output.

Answer (score 0):

Just check it out. When you declare a counter you have to put the type of counter in the Data type. In your case it would be :
Normally you it would also work as @Bart88 proposed.

[Declaration of a counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DCBF.png)